# How can I create a wordpress site as close to Behance as possible with free plugins

Tags: wordpress

I'm fairly new to Wordpress and I was wondering if it was possible to create a clone of the popular creative community Behance (behance.net).

The basic premise is to create a site where users can create accounts, upload portfolios and be featured in sections across the site.

Comment: write your own "plugins" as required.  study some html and javascript as well as server-side computation and sockets.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for a simpler solution that that. 

The beauty of the web and Wordpress in its current state, I feel like there's really no "new" technology that's being created. There's always something built on something.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as I didn't quite get the answer to this question, I found a solution.

There is a Wordpress plugin called Hivepress (https://hivepress.io/). This was the core plug-in I was able to use with only minor modifications (Vendors became artists, Projects and "Listings" became "Projects"). This was changed in a single file called strings.php which is used to change the taxonomies.

I'm sure the plugin has a wide range of applications.

Close to the final product at [www.wadacollective.com](http://www.wadacollective.com).